# how to fix issue with action type reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux

I've created react app with react-reducer.
I've declared types for actions and in the main Reduce I face an issue:
`Can't read property type of undefined`

```
import {ADD_USERS, DELETE_USER, GET_USERS} from '../types'


const initialState = {
    users: [
      {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'Oksana'
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        name: 'Serge'
      },

    ],
    loading: true
}

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_USERS:
        return {
            ...state,
            users: action.payload,
            loading: false

        }
        case ADD_USERS:
          const newId = state.users[state.users.length-1] + 1
          return {
              ...state,
              users: {
                [newId] : {
                  id: newId,
                  name: action.name
                }
              },
              loading: false
  
          }
          case DELETE_USER :
            return {
              ...state, 
              users: state.users.filter(i => i.id !== action.id)
            }
        default: return state
    }

}
```

so here I implement simple get/delete/add methods.

```
export function getUsers (name) {
   return {
     type: GET_USERS,
     payload: name
   }
}
```

....

and this is actions file
I export all the actions, idk where could I make a mistake
the rest of actions I've not mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your switch statement uses `action.type`, however `action` is undefined in at least one of the actions you pass to the reducer. Either add a default value to `action` or add a guard before the switch-statement like so:

```js
export default function(state = initialState, action){
    if (!action) {
       return state
    }

    switch(action.type){
        case GET_USERS:
        return {
            ...state,
            users: action.payload,
            loading: false

        }
    ...
```

As you have a default condition already, adding a default value to `action`, e.g. `action = {}` might be the cleaner solution.

If you use Typescript you could also just do the following:

```js
export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action?.type){
        case GET_USERS:
        return {
            ...state,
            users: action.payload,
            loading: false

        }
    ...
```

Comment: "however `action` is undefined when the state is first initialized." That's not correct.  It gets called with an action `{ type: '@@redux/INIT' }`.  I suspect the `undefined` action is one that this user is dispatching themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the remark @Linda Paiste, you are of course correct. I've adjusted the answer accordingly.